# SSH: Can access externally but not from the local network

Tags: windows, networking, ubuntu, ssh, pfsense

I have a weird problem here, where I can connect to my Ubuntu server via SSH both externally and via VPN, but I can't connect via local network.

I tried via mRemoteNG/Putty and via Open-SSH via PowerShell, but none connected.

Via OpenSSH gives this:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> ssh -vvv <user>@<server>
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2 
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Suporte/.ssh/config error:2 
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2 
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname <server> is address 
debug2: ssh_connect_direct 
debug1: Connecting to <server> [<server>] port 22. 
debug3: finish_connect - ERROR: async io completed with error: 10061, io:0000021D47DAA630
debug1: connect to address <server> port 22: Connection refused 
ssh: connect to host <server> port 22: Connection refused
```

We use pfsense as a firewall (I don't know if it's useful information), and the Ubuntu Server firewall is disabled, and I've already tested disabling the firewall on Windows 10 machines, I added mRemote, putty, openssh (as the microsoft doc advises do) but it didn't work either.

What could it be?

Comment: Are you connecting to it by name or by numeric IP address? If by name, what IP address does it resolve to? What happens if you SSH to it using its private IP address?

Comment: I try to connect via IP. The error I put up there is via IP.

Comment: Which IP? The NAT-private IP that would only work on your LAN, or the publicly routable IP from the WAN port of your NAT gateway router?

Answer (score 1):

If you are connecting via IP-address, your internal network is probably operating on a NATted, non-routable address space (e.g. 192.168.1/24), and the address you are trying to reach is that of the external IP of your (PFSense) router.  If the router does not have hairpin routing setup, your packets aren't going to get redirected to/from the destination.

Moreover, the router may be simply port-forwarding port 22 to a specific destination internal to your network.

If all of that is true, hopefully your internal network DNS is using what is called split-horizon routing, and thus if you use the DNS **name** for the host rather than the port, that will work in both situations.

Alternatively, you can use `~/.ssh/config` host entries with different names and IP addresses to work around, or more complicated strategies involving proxy entries in that same config.

Bottom line, it's (probably) not any issue with `ssh`, but rather with your network routing and DNS not getting your traffic to the right spot.

More information might help if my initial ideas are not correct.

Comment: I think I have this exact issue you are describing. Internal network is NATed, and I want to access the external IP (some dyndns hostname). Can you explain why the port-forwarding does not work from inside the network? I don't really understand it. And what is a hairpin routing setup? How can I configure that?

Comment: @Albert - there are a lot of questions in that comment, and this is not really the forum to answer all of that.  However, I will say that I would **avoid** trying to access the external IP of your network from inside your network - instead, use your internal IP or DNS names if you have a local DNS subnet.  Alternatively, add to your `.ssh/config` with a symbolic name for the IP of your internal host.

Comment: Well, maybe skip the hairpin config question. The port-forwarding would just be an extension to your answer here. But it would also be enough if you can provide links where I can read about the reason why it does not work. Also, I don't want a solution for a single computer. I want that any device in the network just works without any further configuration. Anyway, it actually does work now for me, after I replaced the router. Now I use a Google Nest Wifi router, before I used router from my ISP, which I set to bridge mode now.